# Android: Updating UI using Handler

Tags: android, android-activity, handler

I implemented an Android Application that consists of four activity (A,B,C,D).

A calls B; B calls C and C calls D.

The activity A implements a Handler

```
Handler handler=new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle = msg.getData();
            String key = bundle.getString("Changed");

            if(key.compareTo("NotificationType") == 0){
                String completeStr = bundle.getString(key);

                if(completeStr.compareTo("Message") == 0)
                {
                             // update UI of Activity A
                        }
                 }
         }
   };
```

The Activity D can send a messagge using the hadler.

The question are:

What happens if the Activity A is in background when message is sent from Activity D?

What happens if the Activity A is destroyed before receiving the message through the handler?

Comment: your question is unclear... why are you bothering with activity A in D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Custom `BroadcastReceiver`

Write this in **ActivityD.java**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra("message","hi");
 intent.setAction("com.android.activity.SEND_DATA");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Write this in **ActivityA.java**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // Extract data included in the Intent
   String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
   Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};
```

**Updated**

Now register `Receiver`

```
 registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
  new IntentFilter("com.android.activity.SEND_DATA"));
```

Comment: Thank you @Rstar. So, I can implement a BroadcastReceiver for each Activity that needs to receive message, without worrying about the state of activity. Right?

Comment: @Joseph82 yes you can but don't finish your activty

Comment: Ok @Rstar. But, if the Activity is destroyed before receiving the message using the BroadcastReceiver, when the Activity is created again, the message is received? or the massage is lost?

Comment: @Joseph82 in this case your message will be loast

Comment: Where does the LocalBroadcastManager go ? When I write sendBroadcast(intent); , my IDE doesnt recognize this method ...

Answer (score 1):

To avoid issues you mentioned use [Broadcast messaging system](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).