# Sending text from EditText in Service

Tags: java, android

I have downloaded a BLE sample from Samsung BLE SDK website and i want to edit this code. I want to write a value in an Edittext and send that value with pressing the button. In this sample, it sends the string dummyName = "Praveen" instead and i want to change that.

The problem occurs that ANPServerService class extends Service, so i can't define my EditText there. I just want to send the text in the EditText instead of that "dummyName" string. What should i do ?.

***ANPServerService part:***

```
public class ANPServerService extends Service {

  public static String dummyName = "Praveen";


  public void sendAlert(BluetoothDevice device) {
    Log.d(TAG, "sendAlert");
    byte[] value = null;
    byte cat = (byte) callCategory;
    byte cnt = (byte) dummyCount;

    try {
        String s = dummyName;           
        value = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] attVal = new byte[value.length + 2];

    attVal[0] = cat;
    attVal[1] = cnt;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        attVal[i + 2] = value[i];

    mNewAlert.setValue(attVal);
    mBluetoothGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged(device, mNewAlert, false);

}
```

***Mainactivity part:***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Button.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {          
                 case R.id.button_send_alert:
                     Log.e("MainActivity", "Clicked");
                     if (mService != null)
                         mService.sendAlert(mDevice);
        }
    }
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16332902/1218762

Comment: This example has multiple activities. There is a service and an activity class in my code

Comment: The service is binded with the activity. I just can't define my EditText in the Service part.